# Замена фонового изображения

Tags: javascript

есть див

```
<div class="field field-name-field-season field-type-list-text field-label-inline clearfix">
    <div class="field-label">Сезонность:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Весь год</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Нужно - сделать проверку содержимого

```
<div class="field-item even">Весь год</div>
```

и в зависимости от того, что там - весь год, зима или лето, сменить фоновое изображение у

```
<div class="field-label">Сезонность:&nbsp;</div>
```

хороший человек подсказал вот такое

```
  var elemForImageChange = document.getElementsByClassName("field-item");
  for(el in elemForImageChange){
   if(elemForImageChange.hasOwnProperty(el)){
    switch(elemForImageChange[el].innerHTML) {
     case 'Весь год': elemForImageChange[el].style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/sites/default/themes/raft/images/summer.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / contain ';
     break;
          case 'Лето': elemForImageChange[el].style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/sites/default/themes/raft/images/summer.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / contain ';
     break;
          case 'Зима': elemForImageChange[el].style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/sites/default/themes/raft/images/winter.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / contain ';
     break;

   }
  }
  }
```

но тут есть загвоздка - оно проверяет и меняет фоновый рисунок у field-items, а должно только проверять, а менять у field-label

Пробовал менять, но, видимо, я еще не дошел до уровня, чтобы хорошо понимать логику данного кода(

```
  var elemForImageChange = document.getElementsByClassName("field-item");
  var elemForImageChangeLB = document.getElementsByClassName("field-label");
   for(el in elemForImageChange){
   if(elemForImageChange.hasOwnProperty(el)){
    switch(elemForImageChangeLB[el].innerHTML)
    {
     case 'Весь год': elemForImageChangeLB[el].style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/sites/default/themes/raft/images/summer.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / contain ';
     break;
          case 'Лето': elemForImageChangeLB[el].style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/sites/default/themes/raft/images/summer.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / contain ';
     break;
          case 'Зима': elemForImageChangeLB[el].style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/sites/default/themes/raft/images/summer.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / contain ';
     break;

   }
  }
  }
```

Comment: код проверяет элементы field-item, но менять оно не может, так как див field-item не является родительским для field-label. и нужно проверять от основного дива, от "field field-name-field-season field-type-list-text field-label-inline clearfix"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) и [previousElementSibling](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_previouselementsibling.asp) для перемещения по DOM относительно найденного элемента в данном случае:

```js
var elemForImageChange = document.getElementsByClassName("field-item");
for (el in elemForImageChange) {
  if (elemForImageChange.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
    switch (elemForImageChange[el].innerHTML) {
      case 'Весь год':
        elemForImageChange[el].parentNode.previousElementSibling.style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-6Vvt5okqyYA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAzs/xrQt4JERVaU/photo.jpg?sz=32") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% / contain ';
        break;

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="field field-name-field-season field-type-list-text field-label-inline clearfix">
  <div class="field-label">Сезонность:&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">Весь год</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! За решение и за ссылки!