# Заполнить скрытое поле по клику, взяв значение из другого тега в div блоке

Tags: javascript

Имеется:

```
<div class="listing-item">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <a class="btn" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('IdPrimer').value = 'взять title h2 из этого блока'">Your comment</a>
</div>
<div class="listing-item">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <a class="btn" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('IdPrimer').value = 'взять title h2 из этого блока'">Your comment</a>
</div>
<div class="listing-item">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <a class="btn" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('IdPrimer').value = 'взять title h2 из этого блока'">Your comment</a>
</div>
```

Подскажите как в **value** заполнить **title** (тайтлом) из именно этого блока в котором находится ссылка с классом **listing-item**.

С самим заполнение поля проблем нет.

Класс одинаковый во всех блоках.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ аналогичен [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589222/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/589231#589231). Используем [previousElementSibling](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_previouselementsibling.asp) для перемещения по DOM относительно элемента `a` (`this`) на котором сработал клик.

```html
<input id="IdPrimer" type="text"></input>
<div class="listing-item">
  <h2>title1</h2>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <a class="btn" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('IdPrimer').value = this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.textContent; return false;">Your comment</a>
</div>
<div class="listing-item">
  <h2>title2</h2>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <a class="btn" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('IdPrimer').value = this.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.textContent; return false;">Your comment</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ, у меня еще пару вопросов появились по ходу дела.  Ссылка у меня обернута span тегом, значит надо вылезти из родителя? Как это сделать и возможно этот скрипт сделать отдельно от ссылки, что бы прикрепить его например в footer ?  Извините, но в javascript я полный 0 :)

Comment: @Anatoliy, раз ссылка у вас находится внутри span, то он является родителем. Получаете родителя через [parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) и дальше так же двигаетесь через **previousElementSibling**. Сюда загляните https://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom

Comment: правильно ли я сделал?    
`document.getElementById("formras").onclick = document.getElementById('field44569961').value = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.textContent; return false;`

Comment: @Anatoliy, да, правильно.

Comment: Что то не работает. Поставил этот скрипт в конец страницы. Что может быть?

Comment: вот тестирую http://codepen.io/AnatoliyAV/pen/ObMJGP

Comment: @Anatoliy, а почему вы его в конце страницы поставили? У вас в вопросе и в моем ответе скрипты тут же в теге `a` прописаны, на событии `onclick`. Если вы хотите выделить скрипт в отдельную функцию, то делать это надо так, например: https://jsfiddle.net/jss373j6/

Comment: спасибо, все заработало :)